# What is the probability that a player is the first to roll five doubles?

Tags: probability

**The problem**

Two players take turns rolling two dice. The first player to roll 5 (not necessarily consecutive) doubles wins.

What is the probability that the player going first will win?

**What I've tried**

I initially tried using infinite sums for all the possible outcomes of the game, but I couldn't properly keep track of all the different cases.

My other approach was similar to [this answer for the first person to roll just one number](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3007591/1139902), but I feel that it calculates the probability of five in a row, not five total:

$$p = P(\mathrm{player\,one\,wins\,through\,first\,5\,turns}) + P((\mathrm{player\,one,misses\,a\,double\,on\,one\,of\,the\,five\,turns}) \cap (\mathrm{other \,player\,also\,does\,not\,win}))$$
$$p = (⅙)^5 + (1 - (⅙)^5) * (1 - p)$$
$$p=7776/15551$$

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094234/two-players-flip-a-coin-one-player-has-to-flip-heads-twice-to-win) is another, similar problem.  The methods generalize, though of course it gets messier the more states you need to consider.

Comment: @lulu: No need to consider states here :-)

Comment: @joriki  Interesting.  For this sort of thing, states are almost always easier than the sums.  Maybe not here...

Comment: Why so many close votes ? It is a problem that possibly doesn't have a parallel here, and OP has searched, found no parallel, and tried but failed summing to infinity. Sometimes ( often ?) I find strange decisions on this forum .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability for player $1$ to win on the $k$-th roll is

$$
\binom{k-1}{5-1}\left(\frac16\right)^5\left(\frac56\right)^{k-5}\left(\sum_{j=0}^4\binom{k-1}j\left(\frac16\right)^j\left(\frac56\right)^{k-1-j}\right)\;,
$$

since there are $\binom{k-1}{5-1}$ ways to choose the first four double rolls (the fifth one is the $k$-th) and player $2$ may have rolled between $0$ and $4$ doubles in the meantime.

We need to sum this over $k\ge5$. I couldn’t get Wolfram|Alpha to handle the entire double sum in one go, but calculating it for each $j$ separately has the added advantage that we get the individual probabilities for player $1$ to win with player $2$ having rolled $j$ doubles. The result is

$$
\frac{59560056}{2516421875}+\frac{9891714384}{138403203125}+\frac{914238016776}{7612176171875}+\frac{61841428690464}{418669689453125}+\frac{3450754831279896}{23026832919921875}\\[20pt]=\frac{11808349128075816}{23026832919921875}\;,
$$

or about

$$
2.4\%+7.1\%+12.0\%+14.8\%+15.0\%=51.3\%\;,
$$

which is just a little bit more than half, as might be expected.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I had the right idea. The hard numbers are also much appreciated

Comment: Nice formulation for an Australian Open with twisted rules !